# How to plot subplots from a condition applied on a single column and the data available on another single column of the same dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, subplot, plotly-python

I have a dataframe which is much like the one following:

```
data = {'A':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'B':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        'C':[10,15,23,17,18,26,24,30,35,42,44,42,38,36,34,30,27,25,27,24,1,0,2,3,5,26,30,40,42,50]}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df
```

I would like to have the subplots, the number of subplots should be equal to number of unique values of column 'B'. X axis = Values in column 'A' and Y axis = values in Column 'C'.

The code that I tried:

```
fig = px.line(data_df, 
              x='A', 
              y='C', 
              color='B',
              facet_col = 'B',
              )
fig.show()
```

gives output like

[image]

However, I would like to have the graphs in a single column, each graph autoscaled to the relevant area and resolution on the axes.
Possibility: Can I somehow make use of groupby command to do it?

Since I may have other number of unique values in column 'B' (for example 5 unique values) based on other data, I would like to have this piece of code to work dynamic. Kindly help me.

PS: plotly express module is used to plot the graph.

Comment: Is there a reason that this is tagged `matplotlib` if you are interested in `plotly` solutions? If not, please delete this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stack all subplot in one column, and make sure that each xaxis is independent, just add the following in your `px.line()` call:

```
facet_col_wrap=1
```

And then follow up with:

```
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
```

#### Plot 1: Default setup with `px.line(facet_col = 'B')`

[image]

If you'd like to display all x-axis labels just include this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels = True)
```

#### Plot 2: Show x-axes for all subplots

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'B':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        'C':[10,15,23,17,18,26,24,30,35,42,44,42,38,36,34,30,27,25,27,24,1,0,2,3,5,26,30,40,42,50]}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df

fig = px.line(data_df, 
              x='A', 
              y='C', 
              color='B',
              facet_col = 'B',
              facet_col_wrap=1
             )
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels = True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. This is working as I wanted it to. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sash7 You're welcome! And thank you for the feedback!

Comment: I have noticed an issue in the solution you have mentioned. I would like to have seperate valid x-axes for 3 graphs, since the one as showning in the figure now holds good for the last graph but not the others. Can it be done?

Comment: @Sash7 I'll take another look.

Comment: @Sash7 Better now?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can instead use the argument `facet_row = 'B'` which will automatically stack the subplots by rows. Then to automatically rescale, you'll want to set all of the x data to the same array of values, which can be done by looping through `fig.data` and modifying `fig.data[i]['x']` for each `i`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {'A':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'B':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        'C':[10,15,23,17,18,26,24,30,35,42,44,42,38,36,34,30,27,25,27,24,1,0,2,3,5,26,30,40,42,50]}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.line(data_df, 
              x='A', 
              y='C', 
              color='B',
              facet_row = 'B',
              )
for fig_data in fig.data:
    fig_data['x'] = list(range(len(fig_data['y'])))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: firstly, thank you for your speedy response. This solution works as intended. I needed one solution, got 2 instead.